# How to access object property beginning with a number (SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier)

Tags: javascript, object, properties, syntax-error, notation

I have an object within another object, which im trying to get the value but it always returns "unexpected identifier".

```
snow: Object {3h: 1.3}

console.log(data.snow.3h) //returns Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

console.log(data.snow) //returns Object {3h: 1.3}
```

So how can i get the value of 3h ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data.snow['3h'];
```

Properties accessed with dot notation can't begin with a number.

`snow: Object {3h: 1.3}` could be refactored to `snow: {3h: 1.3}`. It is redundant to type `Object`.

Also, if you wrap your property names in quotes, you can use bizarre property names like:

```
var myObj = {
  '^': 'foo'
};
console.log(myObj['^']);
```

but, I generally stick to more standard names that I can access with dot notation.

Comment: Well thats awkward, really thought I tried ['3h']. Its information from API, I usually stick to standard names. But thanks alot :)